# How to use Jfrog Artifactory packages in an gradle file in an android project

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have uploaded a few binary files in maven format to the jfrog artifactory, but could not seem to be able to resolve them in my project. This is what I am essentially doing,

build.gradle(app)

implementation 'io.sariska:sariska-media-transport:5.0.9'

build.gradle (project level)

allprojects {
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
repositories {
google()
jcenter()
maven {
url = "https://sariska.jfrog.io/artifactory/sariska-media-libs-release-local/"
}
}
}

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Well , in my situation
I have declared a `mavenRepoURL` like this

```
mavenRepoURL = "https:link/to/artifactory"
```

Then I repositories section I have added

```
    maven {
        url = mavenRepoURL
        credentials {
            username artifactoryUser
            password artifactoryPwd
        }
    }
```

and the `artifactoryUser` and `artifactoryPwd` either hardcoded or get from proeties or environment variables with this function

```
artifactoryUser = getConfigurationProperty("ARTIFACTORY_USER", "artifactoryUser", null)
artifactoryPwd = getConfigurationProperty("ARTIFACTORY_PWD", "artifactoryPwd", null)

String getConfigurationProperty(String envVar, String sysProp, String defaultValue) {
    def result = System.getenv(envVar) ?: project.findProperty(sysProp)
    result ?: defaultValue
}
```

This wat I can add to my dependencies like maven central

```
implementation "name:ImportJava:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your answer, I just have one more question. Can we do without the credentials part? The whole reason I was relying on JFrog was to avoid using Github packages that require credentials in the build.gradle file.

Comment: am not 100% sure , but as much as i know , yes you can , you have to disable Jfrog basic auth in order to do that , i think this [link](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/General+Security+Settings) could be helpful for you